# ERRORSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'url' cannot be null

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, html5

Al ejecutar la consulta me tira el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: texto in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dreasity\vistas\nueva-publicacion.php on line 14
>   ERRORSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'url' cannot be null

Cabe destacar que el codigo escrito en **nueva-publicacion.php** es el siguiente:

```
    <?php
    include_once 'app/redireccion.inc.php';
    include_once 'app/controlsesion.inc.php';
    include_once 'app/config.inc.php';
    include_once 'app/conexion.inc.php';
    include_once 'app/publicaciones.inc.php';
    include_once 'app/repositoriopublicaciones.inc.php';
    include_once 'app/validadorpublicaciones.inc.php';

    $publicacion_publica = 0;

    if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
Conexion::abrir_conexion();
/// ESTA ES LA LINEA 14 DEL ERROR /// $validador = new ValidadorPublicacion($_POST['titulo'], $_POST['url'], htmlspecialchars($_POST['texto']), Conexion::obtener_conexion());

if(isset($_POST['publicar']) && $_POST['publicar'] == 'si'){
    $publicacion_publica = 1;
}

if($validador-> publicacion_valida()){
    if(ControlSesion::sesion_iniciada()){
        $publicacion = new Publicacion('', $_SESSION['id_usuario'], $validador-> obtener_url(), $validador-> obtener_titulo(), $validador-> obtener_texto(), '', $publicacion_publica );
        $publicacion_insertada = RepositorioPublicacion::insertar_publicacion(Conexion::obtener_conexion(), $publicacion);

        if($publicacion_insertada){
            Redireccion::redirigir(RUTA_GESTOR_PUBLICACIONES);
        }
    }
    Conexion::cerrar_conexion();
}
    }

    $titulo = 'Nueva publicacion';

    include_once 'plantillas/documento-declaracion.inc.php';
    include_once 'plantillas/navbar.inc.php';
    ?>

    <?php
    if(ControlSesion :: sesion_iniciada()){
    ?>

    <div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2 class="text-center"> Nueva Publicacion </h2>
</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form id="form-nueva-publicacion" method="post" action="<?php echo RUTA_NUEVA_PUBLICACION; ?>">
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
                include_once 'plantillas/form-nueva-publicacion-validado.inc.php';
            }else{
                include_once 'plantillas/form-nueva-publicacion-vacio.inc.php';
            }
            ?>
        </form>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <?php
    }else{
    ?>
    Redireccion :: redirigir(SERVIDOR); 
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    include_once 'plantillas/panel-control-cierre.inc.php';
    include_once 'plantillas/documento-cierre.inc.php';
    ?>
```

**en otros archivos como el validador de publicaciones tengo el siguiente codigo:**

```
<?php 
include_once 'repositoriopublicaciones.inc.php';

class ValidadorPublicacion{
    private $aviso_inicio;
    private $aviso_cierre;

    private $titulo;
    private $url;
    private $texto;

    private $error_titulo;
    private $error_url;
    private $error_texto;

        public function _construct($titulo, $url, $texto, $conexion){
        $this-> aviso_inicio = "<br><div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>";
        $this-> aviso_cierre = "</div>";

        $this-> titulo = "";
        $this-> url = "";
        $this-> texto = "";

        $this-> error_titulo =  $this-> validar_titulo($conexion, $titulo);
        $this-> error_url =  $this-> validar_url($conexion, $url);
        $this-> error_texto =  $this-> validar_texto($conexion, $texto);
    }

    private function variable_iniciada($variable) {
        if(isset($variable) && !empty($variable)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function validar_titulo($conexion, $titulo){
        if(!$this-> variable_iniciada($titulo)){
            return "Debes escribir un titulo";
        }else{
            $this-> titulo = $titulo;
        }

        if(strlen($titulo) > 255){
            return "El titulo no puede ocupar mas de 255 caracteres";
        }

        if(RepositorioPublicacion::titulo_existe($conexion, $titulo)){
            return "Ya hay una publicacion con este titulo, por favor, escribe otro titulo diferente";
        }
    }

    private function validar_url($conexion, $url){
        if(!$this-> variable_iniciada($url)){
            return "Debes escribir una url";
        }else{
            $this-> url = $url;
        }

        if(strlen($url) != strlen(trim($url))){
            return "La URL no puede contener espacio vacios";
        }

        if(RepositorioPublicacion::url_existe($conexion, $url)){
            return "Ya hay una publicacion con esta URL, por favor, escribe otra URL diferente";
        } 
    }

    private function validar_texto($conexion, $texto){
        if(!$this-> variable_iniciada($texto)){
            return "El contenido no puede estar vacio";
        }else{
            $this-> texto = $texto;
        }
     }

     public function obtener_titulo() {
         return $this-> titulo;
     }

     public function obtener_url() {
         return $this-> url;
     }

     public function obtener_texto() {
         return $this-> texto;
     }

     public function mostrar_titulo(){
         if($this-> titulo != ""){
             echo 'value = "'. $this-> titulo . '"';
         }
     }

     public function mostrar_url(){
         if($this-> url != ""){
             echo 'value = " '. $this-> url . '"';
         }
     }

     public function mostrar_texto(){
         if($this-> texto != "" && strlen(trim($this->texto)) > 0) {
             echo $this-> texto;
         }
     }

     public function mostrar_error_titulo(){
         if($this-> error_titulo != "") {
             echo $this-> aviso_inicio . $this-> error_titulo . $this-> aviso_cierre;
         }
     }

     public function mostrar_error_url(){
         if($this-> error_url != "") {
             echo $this-> aviso_inicio . $this-> error_url . $this-> aviso_cierre;
         }
     }

     public function mostrar_error_texto(){
         if($this-> error_texto != "") {
             echo $this-> aviso_inicio . $this-> error_texto . $this-> aviso_cierre;
         }
     }

     public function publicacion_valida(){
         if($this-> error_titulo == "" && $this-> error_url == "" && $this-> error_texto == ""){
             return true;
         }else{
             return false;
         }
     }
}
```

Si alguien pudiera decirme que error hay se lo agradeceria mucho

Answer (score 1):

Te está fallando por una restricción (constraint) que tienes definida en la base de datos por la cual el campo url no puede ser insertado vacío.

> ERRORSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'url' cannot be null

Creo que nunca le das ningún valor, haz un prueba rápida en el constructor:
     `$this-> url = "test";`

Seguramente pase a otro error y habrás verificado que era el problema.

Deberías asegurarte del comportamiento de tu código, y si tiene sentido que guardes el campo url vacío deberás eliminar la constraint de la base de datos.